# Javascript countdown timer error when loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have javascript code for timer countdown. Present output is,  the second digits are decreasing from 60 to 0, but when seconds digits reaches 0, the minute digits are not decreasing. I have added a jsfiddle below, please help me.
jsFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/jyv3gLup/

My javaScript code is added below,

```
function getDifferenceTime(){
var deadline= Date.parse(new Date("2016-11-1T05:00:00"));
var difval= deadline- Date.parse(new Date());
var days= Math.floor(difval/(1000*60*60*24));
var hours= Math.floor( (difval/(1000*60*60))%24);
var minutes= Math.floor( (difval/(1000/60))%60);
var seconds= Math.floor( (difval/1000)%60);
document.getElementById("tes").innerHTML= days + "Days and " +hours + "hours and " + minutes + " Minutes  and"  + seconds;  

}
getDifferenceTime();
setInterval(getDifferenceTime, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getDifferenceTime(){
 var deadline= Date.parse(new    Date("2016-11-1T05:00:00"));
  var diff_val= deadline- Date.parse(new Date());
  var days= Math.floor(diff_val/(1000*60*60*24));
  var hours= Math.floor((diff_val/(1000*60*60))%24);
  var minutes= Math.floor((diff_val/(1000*60))%60);
  var seconds= Math.floor((diff_val/1000)%60);         document.getElementById("date_test").innerHTML= days + "Days and " +hours + "hours and " + minutes + " Minutes  and "  + seconds; 

  var clear_value = document.getElementById("date_test").innerHTML; 
  if( (days==0) && (hours==0) && (minutes==0) && (seconds==0) ){
     clearInterval(clear_value); // clears your timer
     
  }
  
        }// function close
                
getDifferenceTime();
        setInterval(getDifferenceTime, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="date_test"></div>
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3uoe88uh/2/)

Comment: In jsFiddle link, please update your javascript code. there is no js code included here (in your jsfiddle link).

Comment: will the day and hours digit decrease correctly?
also, when the total time reaches 0, then i want to do something, when i should add the if condition?

  @ Bhavin shah

Comment: @saifudeenni.. i have updated my code for `your time reaches 0` condition. and i didn't get you for clock takes 0 minutes.

Comment: @saifudeenni.. I have made update. check if it works for you as per your needs.

Comment: @Bhavin Shah, Thank you very much for your kind response, But i am facing a small problem, i want to get the present date from server by using ajax and i want to add that date into the variable 'deadline'. Can you help me?

Comment: for that you have to ask a new question. as per your question, your answer is given.

Comment: @Bhavin Shah, Thank you very much for your kind response.

Answer (score -1):

You have this: `Math.floor((difval/(1000/60)%60);` it should be `Math.floor((difval/(1000*60)%60);`